# Undeletion followed by lock -- communication denied

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

I deleted [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115516/93440) over a year ago, for reasons I do not remember.  I assume it was due to some hostility in the comments, but I don't know anymore. (The comments had been moved to chat, and apparently been deleted in the meantime; or I just cannot find them.)

Just now, the answer was undeleted by a moderator -- followed by an immediate lock:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.

This keeps me from deleting the answer again. But that's not the issue; I am fine with the answer, and stand by it.

But the lock also keeps me from communicating with the moderator who issued the lock in the (IMHO) appropriate place -- the comments of that answer.

So... can we "resolve the disputes about its content" (if there are any)? I feel this would be much easier if the answer had been undeleted and *not* locked, and the moderator asked whether I would agree to have the answer stand instead of locking it down.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Inviting you to comment.

Comment: Discussion around undeletion and locks should not be in the comments but in Meta, just as you have done.

Comment: FWIW, it's no longer locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the answer was deleted but had a high score and was a good answer, which I felt would still be useful. After asking what should be done in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz), I flagged the post for moderator attention and asked that it be undeleted, which Rory Alsop has done. My flag message was simply:

> This answer was deleted by its author because he was "fed up with the site". The answer itself is high quality and is the second most upvoted answer to this question. I propose undeleting it, perhaps anonymizing the poster if he really does want to dissociate his identity from it.

From the comments, you mentioned that you were fed up with this community:

> @TechnikEmpire: Yeah, CVE count... talk about "fanboy myth". How many CVE-worthy "exploits" does it need when the most effective way to get into any Windows system these days is still to send an email with a trojan attached, and then work from there? -- Don't bother to answer, I'm getting tired of this site already and will probably delete this answer soon-ish just to enjoy the silence again.

It seemed like you were in an argument about both whether or not Linux or Windows was more secure, whether CVE count was an accurate indicator of the security track record of a product, and whether or not memory safe languages solve security issues completely.

I would hope that there are no disputes (seems like that's just a template message for undeletion), since the arguments in the comments are gone, and took place so long ago. I don't think anyone is going to continue such old arguments and if they do, I'm sure you can ask to have the post dissociated from your account so you can continue to enjoy the silence and avoid the drama.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That was what I dimly remembered -- that it was the "noise" from comment chatter that made me delete the answer. As it is unlikely to resume, I am fine with the answer staying as is. I was unaware of the preceding query from you.

Comment: Apologies @DevSolar - was out of signal for a bit. Yes, forest has explained all. It is a really good answer, and worth keeping, but I understand the challenge around noise.